# create textbox for date field on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, date

i'm trying to creat a form which contain textboxs, and i want to use one to fill in date by clicking in that zone
i use asp.net/vb

thks for all yr support

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MaskedEdit control from the AJAX control toolkit.

Sample code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date1" name="date1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender
    TargetControlID="date1" 
    Mask="99/99/9999"
    MessageValidatorTip="true" 
    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
    MaskType="Date" 
    InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
    AcceptNegative="Left" 
    DisplayMoney="Left"
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"/>
```

Take a look at this demo: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: i tried to do like it's demonstrated in video but it doesn't work. i did : 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="date1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="date1">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: No. You're doing it the wrong way. Look at the edited answer above.